# Is 3D Printing SE appropriate for getting feedback on feasibility of a model?

Tags: discussion

As a newbie to 3D printing, I would like to get some feedback on a model I have created before sending it off to get printed. I don't yet own a printer, and I have never sent anything out to get printed before. I am interested in feedback about the following for example:

1. Are any features I have included too big/small/angled/etc. to print reliably?
2. Have I set up my components correctly for optimal printing?
3. Are there any obvious structural issues (weak spots, press-fit issues, etc.)
4. Are there any obvious material/time saving things I should consider?
5. What materials are suitable/best for printing my model?
6. What questions should I ask the supplier before comitting?
7. Any other tips on getting my specific model to succeed.

Since Stack Exchange sites are generally **not** for "primarily opinion based" questions, I'm not sure if this site itself is a suitable location.

### Is the 3D Printing Stack Exchange site a suitable place to get feedback on a specific model before printing?

If not is there a Stack Exchange site similar to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), but for reviewing 3D models?

#### Update

I have not determined where to print the model b/c it likely depends on some of the answers (ex: printing technology, material, etc.) so I don't have someone I can work with directly yet. Also, I'd rather not choose the supplier as my first step b/c they will likely be biased towards whatever they can supply.

Comment: This question is *itself* primarily opinion based, as it asks for a recommendation of a website/forum. Moreover, answers would also inherently be transient, as the website recommended may become unavailable or go out of business. Maybe chat would be a better place to ask this.

Comment: Any 3D forum would work. Keep looking till you find one _you_ like.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden I know... the irony was too great to resist asking anyway! :) Regardless, I have edited my question to be less opinion based. Also, since some SE sites seem to allow this (ex: code review) I wasn't sure if 3D Printing might be the same - since it's a relatively new field I would expect many "facts" about the subject to be merely opinion at this point anyway. I wasn't aware of chat, so I will look into that.

Comment: Can the place that will print it provide any advice? They may have general checklists that you can use, or they may be able to look at your model and let you know if they might have difficulty printing it.

Comment: @mbmcavoy Good idea, however, I have not determined where to print it yet b/c I have not determined all of the requirements (ex: printing technology, material).I have found some checklists on the websites of bigger providers and they have been a good start. However, there are still many things unanswered/unlclear... probably b/c I'm such a newbie.

Comment: You might look into any local "maker spaces" where you can get direct access to machines and a community of people. if your project is large, maybe do smaller "test" pieces to see how they turn out first. Also, I've found it helpful to just watch the machine work as it prints certain features.

Comment: I am +1 this question, because although it _is_ (still rather) opinion based, I think it is quite inquisitive, and I like the list of things to consider. The StackExchange stuff should have been a comment though, as they are not related to the question..

Comment: This question, in its edited form, is more suited for meta.

Comment: Just use a 3d printing facebook group. Also ditto on the Meta comment.

Answer (score 1):

Such a question would be too broad in terms of the number of answers possible, and too specialized to your particular model. The question would be of little value to the site as a whole, as nobody else will ever have the same question and so the answers will be useful only to you.

You should instead ask a question (or multiple questions) about a specific aspect you're unsure about, for instance whether a 1mm wall is thick enough to be printed with SLS, or whether a 35 degree overhang angle will print without supports, etc... This helps build a useful archive of questions, because people will be able to search for your question using general terms, rather than trying to find a question about "Model X".

Comment: Agreed, this is clearly better for forums or facebook groups.

Comment: @StarWind Whether something is better posted somewhere else should not affect whether it is on-topic here. There might be more than one place where you can ask about something...

Comment: Not sure why you are arguing against your own answer. :-)

Comment: @TomvanderZanden, great advice if someone knows enough to know what things to ask.  There is a level of newbie that wouldn't have through yet about issues of wall thickness, overhang, warpage, etc.  Is there somewhere to direct them to that quickly explains the "n" first-order practicality concepts?  Maybe I'll pose this as a question....

Comment: @cmm That kind of newbie should first do a google search and read a guide on the basics of 3D printing. There are already countless guides explaining how to get a model ready for printing (e.g. on 3Dhubs or Shapeways; basically any printing service has one). That kind of thing doesn't really fit well within the scope of a single answer. StackExchange isn't here to explain the basics to someone just barely getting started, it's there to help answer questions when you really get stuck despite doing your homework.